# Twilio: Room History

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video, twilio-python

I am developing an API to retrieve the Twilio access token for a given chat room using Python. However I cannot seem to find a way to retrieve/list the activity history (call history, times when each participant joined the room, started calls and answered, hangup times.) of a specific chat room which we have created. How can I do this?

I first create a Peer-to-Peer room:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-peer-to-peer-room&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x

Then in that room to create user identity access tokens, I use this:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/user-identity-access-tokens#generate-helper-lib

Comment: What "activity history" do you expect exactly?

Comment: Call history, when each participant joined the call, answered, hangup. These events. @deceze

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by access token and chat? It sounds like you are talking about voice calls (call history, times, hangup times, etc).

Comment: Yes @Alan This is related to voice/video calls. I first create a Room and the for that room create user identity access tokens. I have updated the question also. Check this: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/user-identity-access-tokens#generate-helper-lib

Comment: @TechyTee Any joy with finding this information? The documentation is pretty poor!